# Which rear derailleur can I put instead of Shimano Acera

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur, derailleur-rear

My rear derailleur on Cube Aim Race 29" has broken on the holder. Except for this (and prior to the holder breakage) the derailleur has completely stopped working for some reason. It twists into itself and goes almost into the wheel wires. So, it looks like it is broken. So the derailleur completely fell off, and is hanging (hanging on shifter wire). Which new derailleur can I use instead of it? This one is the current one:

https://www.fanaticsport.rs/proizvodi/biciklizam/menjac-zadnji-shimano-acera-rd-r360-sgs-7-8-brzina/

Answer (score 1):

Any Shimano 7/8/9 speed Moutain derailleur will work.

How did it break - the hanger (holder) the deraileur bolts onto is designed to be sacrificial. It is common for this to bend under the kinds of forces that break a derailleur.  You will definitely want to have this checked when you install a new derailleur. Bent hangers can be straightened, but sometimes break when doing so. They are usually replaceable.

It is possible the problem is only with the hanger, in which case straightening or replacing it will fix the problem.

Comment: yes, the hanger broke. In two pieces. It broke in two pieces.

Comment: do you have a specific suggestion? Or any 7/8/9 hanger is fine?

Comment: Hangers are specific to the bike frame.  LBS will be able to source one, or try the likes of https://www.rearmechhanger.com/product/rear-gear-mech-derailleur-hanger-cc244/  (not a recommendation,)